# Need help plotting data from a text file with Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to separate lines of a text file using MATLAB.like first 1-3(modes) in one group next 1-3 in second group and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525240/how-to-separate-lines-of-a-text-file-using-matlab-like-first-1-3modes-in-one-gr)

My .txt file contains the values below. I want to group them like first 1,2 2 2 2...,3 in 1st group,second 1,2 2 2 2...,3 in 2nd group, third 1,2 2 2 2...,3 in 3rd group and so on... please help me to get code for this...**like when i call first group then 1st group values should be plotted.

```
**
mode x   y
1 -4177 3764
2 -4177 3763
2 -4177 3760
2 -4173 3758
2 -4176 3752
2 -4179 3758
2 -4182 3769
2 -4195 3785
2 -4221 3803
2 -4251 3833
2 -4276 3866
2 -4302 3899
2 -4321 3926
2 -4392 3965
2 -4381 3955
3 -12851 -12851
1 -4396 3779
2 -4396 3778
2 -4398 3775
2 -4396 3775
2 -4396 3778
2 -4393 3787
2 -4387 3796
2 -4371 3808
2 -4338 3832
2 -4188 3949
2 -4183 3949
2 -4183 3949
3 -12851 -12851
1 4551 3725
2 4552 3724
2 4555 3719
2 4558 3716
2 4560 3713
2 4558 3713
2 4507 3764
2 4476 3800
2 4437 3842
2 4363 3904
2 4359 3916
3 -12851 -12851
1 4372 3728
2 4372 3725
2 4374 3718
2 4372 3716
2 4371 3719
2 4372 3725
2 4383 3742
2 4408 3773
2 4527 3919
2 4533 3922
3 -12851 -12851
1 312 3742
2 313 3742
2 315 3742
2 313 3742
2 312 3743
2 312 3746
2 318 3920
3 -12851 -12851
```